# How to find static method calls in large Java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, find, static-methods

I'm refactoring some Java code to be more decoupled by changing some static method calls to non-static calls, for example:

```
// Before:
DAO.doSomething(dataSource, arg1, ..., argN)

// After:
dao.doSomething(arg1, ..., argN)
```

My problem is that in a large project, it can be hard to find where static method calls are being made. Is there an easy way to do this, either from the command line or in Eclipse?

Such a tool would need to let me ignore "benign" static method calls such as these (either by not finding them in the first place, or by allowing them to be easily deleted from the search results):

```
String.valueOf(...)
Integer.parseInt(...)
MyClass.someBenignStaticMethod(...)
```

Some clarifications:

- I'm not interested in finding method calls made via reflection
- I don't know what static methods currently exist in this project, so it's not as simple as searching for their callers using Eclipse's "Open Call Hierarchy" command (Ctrl-Alt-H), although an easy way to search for non-private static methods would let me use this approach
- I'm also interested in finding calls to static methods located outside my project, e.g. javax.mail.Transport#send
- I'm looking for a free (as in beer) solution

Comment: But how would you know the instance name to call the method on? Are you saying for every class K there is always also an instance k in scope?

Comment: No, having found an undesirable static method call, I would refactor to remove it, e.g. by using DI to inject an instance of the class containing the static method. But that's all outside the scope of the question; right now I just want to be able to find such static method calls.

Comment: In that case, javap and grep invokeStatic should get you going. I have used that plus some awk in past to create cflow like data.

Comment: If you'd care to add that idea as an answer, I'll give you an up vote! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a small Java program that uses the excellent [ASM](http://asm.objectweb.org/) library. It lets you exclude packages like java.lang, and produces output that looks like this:

```
+ java
  + io
    - File
      # createTempFile(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
+ javax
  + imageio
    - ImageIO
      # read(java.io.InputStream)
      # write(java.awt.image.RenderedImage, java.lang.String, java.io.File)
  + mail
    - Transport
      # send(javax.mail.Message)
    + internet
      - InternetAddress
        # parse(java.lang.String, boolean)
  + xml
    + parsers
      - DocumentBuilderFactory
        # newInstance()
```

I'd prefer something that's more easily built into my existing build process, which uses CheckStyle, but this is the best solution I've come up with so far.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need to search? Why not comment out the static method calls one by one? When you compile it then it will flush out the references.

Comment: This works.  However, when using an IDE, searching might be faster than recompiling for every method.

Comment: This method could miss some call points if static methods are invoked reflectively.

Comment: Yes, but there is almost nothing static analysis do to detect reflection.

Comment: I also want to find any calls made to methods outside my project, for example the infamous javax.mail.Transport#send methods. Also your answer suggests that I already know where the static methods are, so that I can comment them out in the first place.

Comment: I agree with this method. Reflection is an end-case which cannot be solved easily with any other method.

Comment: Reflection can usually be found statically by grepping for `"java.lang.reflect."` (and then eliminating it).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `grep` (`-R` on Linux) to search for initial caps-dot-camel case-open (I don't use it enough to give you the full command line). And then `grep -v` to get rid of some of the rubbish.

Well, really what I'd do is refactor incrementally. Changes a method, and see what breaks (if nothing breaks, delete the code).

Theoretically you could search through the class files looking for `invokestatic`. The FindBugs infrastructure would probably help out here (there may be better starting points).

Comment: I considered FindBugs too, but presumably I would have to write my own checker module (or whatever their plugins are called)?

Comment: Yes. It's two and a half years since I've used it, but I think in this case it'll just be a implementing a couple visitor methods and registering the plugin.

Comment: You'd want something like \b[A-Z][\w\.]+\.[a-z]\w+\\(

I think.

Answer (score 1):

Some IDEs provide support for refactoring.  You can refactor every static method one-by-one.

In Eclipse, you can view the call hierarchy to see all the callers of such method.  To view the call hierarchy you can select the method name and press Command-Alt-H, or Right-Click on symbol and choose 'Open Call Hierarchy).

Comment: The problem is that I don't know where the static method are. So your answer would first require me to search for them; I was hoping to search directly for the static method calls themselves, if possible, as it would be more direct.

Answer (score 1):

We have a product called [nWire for Java](http://www.nwiresoftware.com/java) which might just help. nWire analyzes your code and builds a database of your code components and associations. You can see a brief demo on our web site.

We plan to have reporting capabilities added in the future. In the mean while, if you have some basic experience with databases, you can tap into the nWire repository and, with a simple SQL query, get a list of all your static methods (you can also see the invocations there). nWire uses the [H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/) engine which is open-source and free.

I can assist in accessing the database. Drop me a line to support [at] nwiresoftware.com.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a non-commerical solution; I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Cool. Putting the price sticker on your time is up to you :-)

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be a custom CheckSyle or PMD or ... warning. Currently I have the same challenge and trying it with CheckStyle. It seems to be right easy to write such an extention.